# Hide/Filter tables in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: ssms

I have a SQL database that has several hundred tables in it, but I only need to work with a few.  Is there a way to hide most of the tables from view within SQL Server Management Studio 2008?  Another option would be to create some sort of grouping that would only reference the tables I'm interested in.  Filtering the tables works, but I'm not able add an OR logical operator to include multiple criteria.

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to create a user which only has access the tables you're interested in.
Then connect as that.

Comment: Hadn't considered that, nice thought. However, I'd prefer to have a more UI based solution.

Comment: I guess this is the best we can do?

Answer (score 5):

One way to get tables out of the way in management studio is to mark them with the microsoft_database_tools_support property. This will cause management studio to list those tables under the "System Tables" subfolder. Note that leaving user tables visible to users is usually better practise.

My script template to hide/unhide a table in SSMS:
(Cut'n'paste into query editor, then CTRL+SHIFT+M)

```
EXEC sp_addextendedproperty 
@name = N'microsoft_database_tools_support', 
@value = <Hide? , int, 1>, 
@level0type = 'schema', 
@level0name = N'<Schema Name, sysname, dbo>',
@level1type = 'table', 
@level1name = N'<Table Name, sysname, ?>'
```

Comment: `Leaving user tables visible to users is usually better practise' ... I'm glad this is included in the answer but it seems an understatement.  This is okay if you are by yourself, and there's no team, and no one might have to pick up your work in the future.  Otherwise, this is a scary work-around.

Comment: This is perfect for hiding some legacy table clutter that I just don't want to see in SSMS. Until a more permanent archiving solution is implemented, begone from my sight.

Answer (score 4):

I realize this is an old question, however in SQL Server Managaement Studio 2008, you can filter by name, schema, owner, or creation date by right clicking on tables, views, stored procedures object "folders" and clicking `Filter > Filter Settings`

Comment: As read in the question: "Filtering the tables works, but I'm not able add an OR logical operator to include multiple criteria."